# How to set value from server in Input and change it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this input, and by default there should be value from server

```
              const [nameValue, setNameValue] = useState("");

              <TextField
                id="outlined-read-only-input"
                label="Display Name"
                variant="outlined"
                value={nameValue !== '' ? nameValue : name || '' }
                onChange={(e) => setNameValue(e.target.value)}
                onBlur={() => setName({ variables: { name: nameValue } })} 
              />
```

**name** - server response

**nameValue** - new value that I need to send to the server

But when I try to change value and 1 sign remains and I want to erase it, the value returned by default

Problem is here `value={nameValue !== '' ? nameValue : name || '' }` but I don't know how to fix it

```
export const getMeData = gql`
  query {
    me {
      apsTraining
      backgroundCheck
      city
      contactPreference
      dateOfBirth
      email
      familyCupSignedUp
      gender
      id
      name
      phone
      programWaiver
      state
      stripeEnabled
      zip
    }
  }
`
const { data } = useQuery(getMeData);
const name = data ? data.me.name : null
```

Comment: please post the whole component, how does name gets into the component? is it a prop? async result?

Comment: @llamar added. I got it with graphql

Comment: so you want to have the custom value, and if empty - show the server value?

Comment: @llamar no, default value in Input should be the server value, but i need to be able to change it, and send new value to server and of course it means that default value will change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of an checking if its an empty string initiate the nameValue to be null when the component mounts, since **empty string ("")** is not the same as **null**, the **nameValue can be null only once**, and once **nameValue** changes it will always be a string.

```
 const [nameValue, setNameValue] = useState(null);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        id="outlined-read-only-input"
        label="Display Name"
        variant="outlined"
        value={nameValue !== null ? nameValue : name || ""}
        onChange={(e) => setNameValue(e.target.value)}
        onBlur={() => setName({ variables: { name: nameValue } })}
      />
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: God bless you! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You can set state to default to name prop (coming from graphQL).

```js
 const [nameValue, setNameValue] = useState(name);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        id="outlined-read-only-input"
        label="Display Name"
        variant="outlined"
        value={nameValue}
        onChange={(e) => setNameValue(e.target.value)}
        onBlur={() => setName({ variables: { name: nameValue } })} 

      />
    </div>
  );
```